# Invalid object name Customer

Tags: c#

error :     `da.Fill(ds,"Customer")`;  what should I do on it? please help me..

```
   public void LoadRecord()       
      {
        con.Open();
        string sql="SELECT * FROM Customer";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds,"Customer");           
        dgvview.DataSource=ds.Tables["Customer"];
        con.Close();
     }
```

Comment: @Satpal still has the same error..

Comment: Yes You need to use `da.Fill(ds)` but I think this will give you an compile time error. As you described the error as *Invalid object name Customer* then I think you have to make sure that connection string is correct and db has `Customer` table.

Comment: @Sachin still the same error also..

Comment: @may is it possible that you have different table name, like `CustomerS` in database? Or you querying wrong database?

Comment: I wish I could see your connection string. Something is telling me that it is wrong (or just a bit wrong otherwise you couldn't connect at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to only select the columns you do need:
e.g.:

```
string sql="SELECT ID, Name FROM Customer";
```

Also, you can apply the datasource like this:

```
dgvview.DataSource=ds;
```

Otherwise your code looks OK.

**Please also doublecheck if you can launch the query on the database.**

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** there is no problem with your code for sure, `Invalid Object Name` Error is coming because you are referering to wrong `Database` Name hence it could not identify the Table `Customer`.

**Solution :** check wether you are referening to proper database name or not.

**Note :** check your database name for `Initial Catalog` parameter in your `connection string`

```
String ConnectionString = "Data Source=hostname;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;uid=myid;pwd=mypasword;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: Note - database name can also be specified with `database` parameter